Solved: Issues Downgrading to Kernel 6.3.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am currently facing issues while trying to downgrade to Kernel 6.3.0 on my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS system. I am experiencing USB and ZFS module loading problems.
The reason for downgrading is that my USB card (ID 2109:0711 VIA Labs, Inc. VL711 and ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub) stopped working on the newer kernel. According to https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:2109-0817 , the least compatible kernel with my card is the 6.3 kernel.
Here are the details of what I have tried so far:
Current Kernel Version:
6.8.0-39-generic
Steps Taken:
Installed Kernel 6.3.0:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-6.3.0-060300-generic linux-modules-6.3.0-060300-generic linux-headers-6.3.0-060300-generic
Updated Initramfs:
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 6.3.0-060300-generic
Updated Grub:
sudo update-grub
Reinstalled ZFS:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install zfs-dkms
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 6.3.0-060300-generic
Issues Encountered:
During Boot:
I selected the 6.3.0 kernel from the GRUB menu and received the following errors:
"xhci host not responding to stop endpoint command"
"xhci host controller not responding, assume dead"
"Failed to load ZFS modules. Manually load the modules and exit."
Tried Manually Loading ZFS Modules:
From the (initramfs) prompt:
modprobe zfs
exit
This did not resolve the issue.
Attempted to Regenerate Initramfs:
When running:
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 6.3.0-060300-generic
Them i encountered warnings about missing modules:
W: Kernel configuration /boot/config-6.3.0 is missing, cannot check for zstd compression support (CONFIG_RD_ZSTD)
W: missing /lib/modules/6.3.0
Additional Details:
The USB issues started after a recent update. Before the update, the USB card was working fine.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 pci=nomsi,noaer xhci_hcd.quirks=270336"
The ZFS modules seem to be causing boot issues.
If the card works on the 6.8.0-39-generic kernel like it did on the 6.3.0-060300-generic kernel, that would be great.
There's an USB hub, which is connected to the pci VIA Labs card, it works fine directly on the motherboard, but I am hitting the 14 USB device limits due to the X99 chipset limitation.
Questions:
How can I resolve the "xhci host not responding" and "xhci host controller not responding, assume dead" errors?
What is the correct way to manually load ZFS modules if the automatic method fails?
Are there any additional steps to ensure the 6.3.0 kernel and its modules are properly installed and configured?
Is there a specific way to fix the missing kernel configuration and modules warnings during initramfs generation?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The 6.3 kernel is not supported on any version of Ubuntu. If you have issues with Ubuntu 24.04 and kernel 6.8 try 6.9 as it is known to work. Otherwise you question is off topic.

I changed to 6.6 and the card worked again
